# How to get whole text from MultiAutoCompleteTextView?

Tags: android, multiautocompletetextview

I am using `MultiAutoCompleteTextView`.

When I select any item from a drop down then it displays in the `MultiAutoCompleteTextView` after I put some text in it.  Adding some text after, I select a username from the auto complete and it comes in below the line I want it to.

I would like to get the text in the line with `MultiAutoCompleteTextView` having enough space to show it.

[image]

Comment: Put some code of implementation to understand the issue.

Comment: how can i get whole content MultiAutoCompleteTextView ? after enter or space i didn't get any content using getText.